# How to call async function with await within coroutine function in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a coroutine as follows:

```
IEnumerator CountingCoroutine()
{
    while (true)
    {
        DoSomething();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}
```

I need to call some async function within it. If I wrote it as follows, the compiler complains:

```
async IEnumerator CountingCoroutine()
{
    while (true)
    {
        DoSomething();
        await foo();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}
```

What is the proper wait to call some async functions per second?
P.S. I could abandon the whole coroutine function and use update with time counting mechanism, and mark the update function as async. But I'm not sure if it's safe or recommended.

Solution with recommendations from @derHugo:

```
IEnumerator CountingCoroutine()
{
    while (true)
    {
        DoSomething();
        var task = Task.Run(foo);
        yield return new WaitUntil(()=> task.IsCompleted);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`Task.IsCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task)

like

```
private IEnumerator CountingCoroutine()
{
    while (true)
    {
        DoSomething();

        var task = Task.Run(foo);
        yield return new WaitUntil(()=> task.IsCompleted);
    }
}
```

which starts running a new Task as soon as the one before has finished.

You could extend this in order to start a new task earliest about every second or latest when the previous task finishes after a second like e.g.

```
private IEnumerator CountingCoroutine()
{
    var stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    while (true)
    {
        DoSomething();
        stopWatch.Restart();
        var task = Task.Run(foo);
        yield return new WaitUntil(()=> task.IsCompleted);

        var delay = Mathf.Max(0, 1 - stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds * 1000);

        // Delays between 1 frame and 1 second .. but only the rest that foo didn't eat up
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        // or you could with a bit more calculation effort also 
        // even avoid the one skipped frame completely
        if(!Mathf.Approximately(0, delay)) yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    }
}
```

Or if you don't care about the finishing and only want to call this as you say every second then simply do

```
private IEnumerator CountingCoroutine()
{
    while (true)
    {
        DoSomething();

        Task.Run(foo);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}
```

Note however that this way you lose all control and will never know if and when one of these tasks has finished and might get multiple concurrent tasks running/failing etc

---

As alternative you could probably also go the other way round and use something like [Asyncoroutine](https://github.com/zsaladin/Asyncoroutine)) .. you might have to watch out for things landing on a background thread though.

---

**Update**

Nowadays I would rather suggest to give [`UniTask`](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask) (also available via [OpenUPM](https://openupm.com/packages/com.cysharp.unitask/)) a try! It is a lightweight async Task implementation and additionally provides seamless async <-> Unity main thread integrations.

Comment: Thank you! For now I use something similar to your second solution `_ = foo();`. And also as you pointed out that this way might cause complex conflicts. I'll redesign it and make the time counting coroutine to stop, and resume when works are done.

Comment: note that simply using `_ = foo();` might run your `foo` synchronous since it isn't awaited and the Coroutine not async

Comment: Noted. I just understood your first solution. Please see my newly edited codes in the question. I'm new to the keyward `yield`. In my understanding the first yield will not block the caller's other codes, but blocks whatever after this line. And when the task is completed, it will be picked up and run from the next line, in this case the 2nd yield. In this case this loop might take the time of 1 second plus the time running foo(). Am I right?

Comment: @ArtS yes .. but I just also edited the answer and added a third example (it is now the second ^^) where I substract the time that `foo` took from the 1 second and delay only by the rest. So either way it will definitely wait until `foo` is done but after that only the rest of the time but at least one frame

Comment: `yield` works a bit different though: It is called every frame by the Unity `Update` routine. However e.g. `WaitUntil` itself is an `IEnumerator` which simply returns `true` until the condition is full filled. So in simple words lets say the Coroutine is "stuck" until it can move on to the next line ;)

Comment: Could you kindly check out this question please? It's a strange bug that occurred using what we discussed here. Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64335525/task-can-not-be-completed-without-calling-print-in-unity

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the above answers. These codes were helpful for me.

```
var task = Task.Run(foo);
yield return new WaitUntil(()=> task.IsCompleted);

lobby = t.Result;
```

But I faced a problem that my async function doesn't work in the Task context because the function code should be run in the main thread.

To solve it, I directly executed the async function in the coroutine instead of the Task context. These are my code to execute the async function in the coroutine.

```
private IEnumerator TransactionUpdater()
{
...
        var task = GetTransactionReceipt(txid);
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => task.IsCompleted);
        var receipt = task.Result;
...
}

async private Task<TransactionReceipt> GetTransactionReceipt(string txid)
{
        try
        {
            var provider = new JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL);
            return await provider.GetTransactionReceipt(txid);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the result of the Task here is an example:

```cs
IEnumerator RefreshLobbyCoroutine()
{
    var delay = new WaitForSecondsRealtime(2);
    while (lobby != null)
    {
        // Run task and wait for it to complete
        var t = Task.Run(async () => await Lobbies.Instance.GetLobbyAsync(lobby.Id));
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => t.IsCompleted);

        // Task is complete, get the result
        lobby = t.Result;
        yield return delay;
    }
}
```